# Turn Raspberry Pi off but keep the RAM powered?

Tags: power-management, memory

Is it possible to turn almost everything on a Raspberry Pi off (CPU GPU etc), except for the ram?

Basically putting the Pi in a low power state but preserving whatever it was doing at the moment on which it was turned off?

Comment: Isn't that called "Sleep"?

Comment: Do not be sorry. It is actually better to keep the topics separate. You did right.

Comment: Rasp may not be the right CPU for what you are considering. How much RAM are you thinking about anyway?

Comment: Hi, my original plan was actually to have a separate device which would store the data and have the program that generates the data run on the Raspberry Pi, but I have now learned that building such a device is very difficult so I thought about having the Pi save the data to it's own RAM and keeping only the RAM enabled when a low power state is needed, but it seems like that is not possible and the Raspberry Pi doesn't have enough RAM, I need 2 gigs. I think I underestimated this problem and there is no easy solution.

Comment: how fast is the data being generated? can you use a usb flash drive for storage?

Comment: Sadly no, I would need to replace it every week or so because of all the writes.

Comment: Cloud based storage. Or a usb hard drive.

Comment: There is nothing like that

Answer (score 1):

No, the DRAM needs to be refreshed which is not a function you can run independent of the GPU. It is all or nothing.

Comment: Actually, most modern DRAM chips do have a self-refresh mode. But it must be explicitly entered before shutting down the rest of the system.